# How to create and normalise this SQL relational database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, triggers, foreign-keys

I am trying to design an SQL lite database. I have made a quick design on paper of what I want.

So far, I have one table with the following columns:

- `user_id` (which is unique and the primary key of the table)
- `number_of_items_allowed` (can be any number and does not have to be
  unique)
- `list_of_items` (a list  of any size as long as it is less than or equal
  to number_of_items_allowed and this list stores item IDs)

The column I am struggling the most with is `list_of_items`. I know that a relational database does not have a column which allows lists and you must create a second table with that information to normalise the database. I have looked at a few stack overflow answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444251/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-db-column) one, which says that you can't have lists stored in a column, but I was not able to apply the accepted answer to my case.

I have thought about having a secondary table which would have a row for each item ID belonging to a `user_id` and the primary key in that case would have been the combination of the item ID and the `user_id`, however, I was not sure if that would be the ideal way of going about it.

Comment: I would not have a column `list_of_items`, I would definitely prefer the other table with a composite unique index of userID and itemID. No primary key would be needed, though you could have one, as long as the other two columns are a unique composite index to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following schema with 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  user TEXT NOT NULL,
  number_of_items_allowed INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(number_of_items_allowed >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  item TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users_items (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  item_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES items (item_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id)
);
```

For this schema, you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `users_items` which checks if a new item can be inserted for a user by comparing the user's `number_of_items_allowed` to the current number of items that the user has:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_number_before_insert_users_items 
BEFORE INSERT ON users_items
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) >=
            (SELECT number_of_items_allowed FROM users WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id)
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'No more items allowed')
     END;
END;
```

You will need another trigger that will check when `number_of_items_allowed` is updated if the new value is less than the current number of the items of this user:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_number_before_update_users 
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) > NEW.number_of_items_allowed
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'There are already more items for this user than the value inserted')
     END;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0bd2b460482f6313c8090f802af9ae87).

Comment: Thanks. I have used your database and updated it to allow for expiration of credits, which can be seen on [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kNcpTN1neadgPJsAmh4pzL/1) fiddle. Do you know why I am getting an error on it?

Comment: @knowledge_seeker this probably a bug from the fiddle. Here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d056c79d4a841122167d3628ed94b9d9 there is no error.