# Insert multiple new rows for each key matching a format

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, key

I created a set of three tables similar to the ones created in this answer [How to store a list in a db column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444251/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-db-column/444268#444268), with the difference being that my keys are each composed of a pair of columns instead of single columns.

**Foo:**

| Chr1 | Chr2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| a | b |
| b | a |
| b | b |

**Fruits:**

| Type | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Berry | Cranberry |
| Berry | Blueberry |
| Aggregate | Blackberry |
| Berry | Blackberry |
| Berry | Lingonberry |
| Aggregate | Raspberry |
| Berry | Raspberry |
| Berry | Boysenberry |

**FooFruits:**

| Chr1 | Chr2 | Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Foo will be ~75 rows

Fruits will be ~600 rows, and has other columns that are not used here.

Eventually FooFruits will be very long because I will be assigning each Foo a large list of fruits.

All of these columns are nvarchar(50).

I made the composite keys because there are guaranteed to be duplicates of each [Chr1] and [Chr2], or each [Type] and [Name], but there can't be duplicates of the pair.

I am able to use the format mmxx gave (in a different order for my purpose)

```
INSERT FooFruits([Chr1], [Chr2], [Type], [Name])

SELECT [Chr1],[Chr2],'berry','cranberry' FROM Foo WHERE [Chr1] ='a' and [Chr2]='b'
```

to create a new row in my "FooFruits" table.

These databases will be accessed and modified with a Python program, most likely using QSqlTableModels in PyQt5.

**The actual question**

Is there some way to insert a row for everything where `[Name] = '%nberry'`, so it would insert rows for 'cranberry', 'lingonberry', and 'boysenberry'? I could `SELECT [Name] FROM Fruits WHERE [Name] = '%nberry'` and then loop through each result and run individual inserts for them, but that seems very inefficient.

I also want to know what would happen to corresponding rows in "FooFruits" if I deleted one of the rows in "Foo" or "Fruits".

Comment: What DB are you using?  How are you joining the tables together? You can use `LIKE` for what you are referencing.  Also, since FooFruits is a table and not a view, unless you put a Foreign Key on it, nothing will happen if you delete rows from Foo or Fruits.

Comment: I am using a Microsoft SQL Server, and I have foreign keys connecting the tables so that nothing can be added to FooFruits that is not either a proper Fruit or Foo.

Comment: Update:
I reformatted my query and it was able to work with `Like`, which I had tried earlier and it hadn't worked. Probably made some other error. Thanks for making me try that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved. I had tried using `Like` earlier, but clearly had made some other error at the same time.

This

```
INSERT FooFruits([Chr1], [Chr2], [Type], [Name])

SELECT 'a','b','berry',[Name] FROM Fruits WHERE [Name] LIKE '%nberry'
```

worked. Thanks, [Del](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299760/del).